# Video game where the player can research a cure for zombies

Tags: story-identification, video-games, zombie

I played this game a long time ago on Armor Games back when flash player was still supported. In this game, the player plays as a group of survivors in a zombie apocalypse that are slowly taking back the city. One of the ways the game can end is when the player researches the cure for the zombie disease. If the player gets that ending, a cutscene plays where a doctor in a full hazmat suit injects a captured zombie with the cure, and the infected is shown turning human again.

Another task that the player can accomplish is to draft a Constitution for the new government.

Does anyone know what the game is?

Comment: I think the game is Rebuild https://www.kongregate.com/games/sarahnorthway/rebuild But i cannot find any good images, and the game is not playable without flash.

Comment: I can't check, because I'm at work, but apparently Flashpoint is a combination of emulator and database of games, that my preliminary Google search seems to indicate might include *Rebuild*.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots If you can get it to work, then you are more than welcome to write an answer to this one. I do not have time today.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is *[Rebuild 2](https://rebuild-series.fandom.com/wiki/Endings_(Rebuild_2))*, as per Bjorn's suggestion. The endings page here mentions endings for [finding a cure](https://rebuild-series.fandom.com/wiki/Endings_(Rebuild_2)#Find_the_Cure), and for [drafting a constitution](https://rebuild-series.fandom.com/wiki/Endings_(Rebuild_2)#Draft_a_Constitution).

### Finding a Cure

[image: Researching in Secret] [image: Reclaimed laboratory]

> **After this ending**
> You will be rewarded with a short scene showing the reversement of an infected in timelapse.

### Drafting a Constitution

> **After this ending**
> You will be rewarded with a short scene of an article who writes about your new constitution.

Apparently, [both endings are available in the first Rebuild](https://rebuild-series.fandom.com/wiki/Endings_(Rebuild_1)) as well.

[image: Rebuild: Cure Ending]
[image: Rebuild: Constitution ending]

But there is no hazmat suit.

*Rebuild 3: Gangs of Deadsville* definitely has a cure storyline, as seen [here](https://youtu.be/uY60yUBXQbY?t=1342), but there don't seem to be any hazmat suits involved, and I haven't seen mention of a Constitution Ending.